# Embed facebook live with html5 video player script

Tags: facebook, video-streaming, html5-video

There is any way to embed facebook live video into html page, with a custom video player script like mediaelementjs for example? Using rtmp that provide facebook when you do a live.

I have tested with this embed :

```
<video width="360" height="203" id="player1" src="rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:443/rtmp/1327296050643313?ds=1&s_l=1&a=ATiweM9l1fKQFUUB" autoplay="true" type="video/rtmp" controls="controls"></video>
```

and JS init

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */);
</script>
```

But nothing in the page seems playing. someone have tested a player (maybe html5 player) for facebook live embed in html page?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player ?

Comment: I'm looking for custom player, like videojs or another one

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the `preview_url` ? I haven't tested it, but in the documentation seems to be a method to get a preview_url in RTMP strem to preview the video you are recording.

[Link to the documentation in Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/production-broadcasts#preview)

*The problem for this workaound would be that the preview_url is limited to 4 hours and 10 viewers.*